# How can I programmatically update Outlook meeting with ASP.net meeting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, outlook

I have created a vb.net class library to create and cancel Outlook meeting requests to users with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442680/how-can-i-programmatically-cancel-an-outlook-meeting-with-asp-net-vb).

How can I update those calendar entries or which method to be passed for updating the saved meeting entry? I have tried with method "Update" but that doesn't remove the previously added meeting from calendar and add new meeting request into calendar.

Comment: May we see the code you have so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to: Update calendar events that were imported by iCalendar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314937/how-to-update-calendar-events-that-were-imported-by-icalendar-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314937/how-to-update-calendar-events-that-were-imported-by-icalendar-file). I was missing "SEQUENCE".

Answer (score 0):

This means the meeting UID is different from the one you already sent before.